# Typescript server in VSCode incorrectly reports unused private variable

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Why does typescript report that the variable is not used even though it is referenced inside `_close()` method?

The weird thing is that if I remove the private keyword, the warning goes away.

Please note that even though it is a warning, it still does not compile.

[image]

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noUnusedLocals": true, <-- This line
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The message doesn't tell that the variable is never **used**. It tells the variable is never **read**. What's the point of having a variable if you never read its value?

Comment: @JBNizet I was too dumb to tell the difference between `never read` and `never used`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript is complaining that you never **read** the variable. Your `_close` method only sets it. And I think typescript rightly complains, as what's the point of a storing something if you are never interested in using it's value later?

Moreover, the error goes away if you remove the `private` modifier because then the value can be read by anyone who has an instance of the class. So typescript can no longer verify that the value is never read (since it might be used by others). But with `private`, it knows only the class methods can access it, so if it doesn't see the value get read anywhere within the class itself, it will produce an error.